# How to save co-ordinates and reference them later, using C# and WebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

This might be a little bit of a peculiar question to ask as I'm sure you don't see something like this every day.

I'm developing a program that will automatically go through a series of questions and choose the correct answer for the user. The way this works is it first goes through the questions by pressing a button on the page called "Check Answer", finding the answer that is correct by its RGB color and (in the near future), go through the questions again, this time clicking the correct answers based on the information we gathered earlier.

Here is the problem; obviously I don't want to press the coordinates of all the correct answers on just one question and do that every single question! What I'm looking to do instead is save these coordinates I find to a variable, somehow associate them with whatever question they were found on and, when automatically filling in the correct answers, only reference the coordinates corresponding to that specific question.

What I'm basically saying in a nutshell is I want to associate certain coordinates with certain "parts" of a page.

Here is some code from the program:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> unfiltered = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"));
Console.WriteLine(unfiltered.Count);
List<IWebElement> filtered = unfiltered.Where(f => f.GetCssValue("color") == "rgba(180, 137, 59, 1)").ToList();
Console.WriteLine(filtered.Count);
foreach (IWebElement element in filtered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Location.X);
    Console.WriteLine(element.Location.Y);
    //Save coordinate(s) to variable pertaining to specific question?
}
```

The code above is in a loop in my program. Once it gets all the coordinates matching the specific RGB color, it will move on to the next question and it will run this code again. I want to be able to save `element.Location.X` and `element.Location.Y` to variables for whatever question it is on.

Comment: Are you sure the answers aren't shuffled each time they are asked? How do you know the coordinates are exactly the same each time? If you are sure that the answers aren't shuffled, I would go by the index of the answer rather than the coordinates. The coordinates on the page can be affected by many things... the index won't.

Comment: Hi @JeffC; I know for a fact that the questions and the answers are not shuffled in any way. Basically, the way things are written right now, my WebDriver finds everything by the color that would identify a correct answer, but you're right in regards that this is not the most practical way to go about doing this. When you say, "I would go by the index of the answer", what exactly do you propose I replace this mechanism with? I honestly could not think of any other way to find the correct answer on the page (due to the page was structured). If possible, could I have a code sample?

Comment: If you will post an HTML sample, I will try to post a code sample. I'm basically assuming that the answers are radio buttons or the like. You can capture a collection of them for a given question and then find that the 3rd answer is the correct one and then record Q1 A3 somewhere rather than coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work :)

```
public class QuestionElement
{   
    public IWebElement Element { get; set; }

}

public class QuestionItem
{
    public string QuestionID { get; set; }
    public list<QuestionElement> Elements;
}

public class QuestionItems
{
    public SortedList<QuestionItem> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class PopulateQuestionItem()
{


    public void AddQuestionResult(string questionID, QuestionItems questionItems, string colorItem)
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> unfiltered = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"));

        List<IWebElement> filtered = unfiltered.Where(f => f.GetCssValue("color") == colorItem).ToList();
        QuestionItem questionItem = new QuestionItem() { QuestionID = questionID };

        foreach (IWebElement element in filtered)
        {
            QuestionElement item = new QuestionElement()
            {
                Element = element

            };
            questionItem.ElementsAdd(item);
        }

        questionItems.Questions.Add(questionID, questionItem);

    }
```